# Some categories missing on wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category

Tags: categories, taxonomy

When I go to [/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9Wkc.png)

it says there are 19 categories, but will only list 13 of them.  There is no second page to go to.  If I Search Categories for " ", all 19 do show up.  If I click the "Parent Category" on the left, it shows all 19 in the drop down.  Pretty much everywhere else except for the main category list page.  What would cause this issue and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Can't answer your question, but I just had a poke around with [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) and this is the query that seems to get all the categories (it runs last so you don't have to search through every single query). If you can be bothered running this against your database and having a poke around with the results might help you figure out what's going on.

Or maybe you want to use Query Monitor to double check what query gets run for you to see why not all the categories are returned.

```
SELECT t.*, tt.*
FROM wp_terms AS t
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt
ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category')
ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

Edit: And if this query shows all your categories, then you know that something else is removing them from this view somehow.

Comment: Thanks, that query does return all 19 categories.  I may look into using Query Monitor if no other solution presents itself.